# Talend job throwing error on a simple SELECT from tSnowflakeInput component

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, talend

I am pretty new to Talend. I am trying to obtain data from a Snowflake DB. It's a simple query as follows:

```
"SELECT TOP 1 ACCOUNTID FROM CONTACT"
```

When I run the job, it throws an error with regards to processing the query, as in screenshot 1. Would appreciate your inputs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi - the 3rd line from the bottom probably contains useful information but it is truncated in the image. Please add the settings for the Snowflake  connection to your question (replace anything confidential with x's)

Comment: Hi @NickW. Thank you for your quick response. I added another screenshot with the connection details to the post. The line that you pointed out says - "Caused by: net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeSQLException: JDBC driver internal error: Fail to retrieve row count for first arrow chunk: null."

Comment: Couple of thoughts: is there a setting for "role" somewhere? If you use the same settings (user/role/warehouse) in the Snowflake Web UI, does the query run?

Comment: if not already done, please raise a snowflake support case, using the snowflake community or sending an email to Support@snowflake.com.

Please attach the complete JDBC logs and we would be happy to assist.

https://community.snowflake.com/s/

Comment: Hi @NickW. I did look into the "Role" in the connection settings and playing around with it, but nothing worked. Have raised a Snowflake case now.

Comment: @FKayani thanks for the input. We have created a case (or probably will create in a few minutes once a person with access can create one).

Answer (score 0):

- I was also encountering the same issue. The tSnowflakeInput is not
  even getting the simple queries (even default i.e. all records).
- Environment while I was encountering this issue
  Talend Big Data Open Studio: 8.0.1
  Java SDK - 21
- While I removed my Java SDK from 21 to Open Java SDK 11,
  tSnowflakeInput is working very fine. I have not made any changes in
  the previous system.
- Make sure to set your environment variables while changing the Java
  SDK.

Note: replying this old questions for aiding future developers